# Outlook.exe process not ending when called from VBA in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a form in Access 2007 that opens when Outlook opens, and the following code is in the `Form_Load()` event:

```
Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As MailItem
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

msg = "This is a test"

bdy = "<p style='font-family: Calibri; font-size:11pt'>This is just a test</p>"

rec = "me@myemail.com"

With objMail
    .To = rec
    .Subject = msg
    .HTMLBody = bdy
    .Display
    .Send
End With

Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing

Application.Quit
```

The code works, meaning that an email is sent and Access closes. The MSACCESS.EXE process disappears from Windows Task Manager (Windows 7) but the OUTLOOK.EXE process stays open and the CPU sits at 25% until the memory usage reaches about 500MB. At that point, the CPU usage for the process drops to 0% but it doesn't exit. I let it sit overnight and the process never exited.

After some testing, it seems the problem is that I'm launching Access from a batch file that's kicked off by Windows Task Scheduler. The batch file consists of:

```
`Start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSAccess.exe" c:\myDb.accdb`
```

If I just double click the .bat file, or open the .accdb file manually, OUTLOOK.EXE closes along with MSACCESS.EXE

What am I missing here? Most of the sample code I've come across basically looks like my code.

**UPDATE**

Per user `tbur`, the solution was "In the Task Scheduler, make sure under the 'General' tab, you have 'Run only when user is logged on' and 'Run with highest permissions' both checked.".

Not really the solution I wanted, but it did fix the problem. The problem now is that the Windows 7 PC running this code will reboot after a Windows update, and most of the tasks are scheduled to run in the middle of the night.

Answer (score 1):

```
objOL.Quit
```

Setting `objOL` to `Nothing` just releases the reference i.e. severs the relationship between `objOL` and the Outlook application; it doesn't close the application.

Comment: I tried this, adding it right above the `Application.Quit` line and now the MSACCESS.EXE process isn't ending either. But only when Access is launched from the Windows Task Scheduler. If I open the .accdb file, everything exits properly.

Comment: In the Task Scheduler, make sure under the 'General' tab, you have 'Run only when user is logged on' and 'Run with highest permissions' both checked.

Comment: @tbur - that did fix my issue. I had it set to 'run whether user is logged in or not' since the PC this resides on has a tendency to reboot itself after Windows updates. It also doesn't seem to matter if I use `objOL.Quit` or not, but I'll leave it in there just in case.

Comment: @Jeff Brady I'm glad that fixed it! That glitch has burned me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (at the end of your code):
`objOL.Quit`